# Spark isolate time taken for reading from external DB

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am looking to measure how much time is taken in my Spark job for the IO part of reading from an external DB. My code is

```
 val query = s"""
            |(
            | select
            |  ...
            |) as project_data_tmp """.stripMargin

      sparkSession.time(
        sparkSession.read.jdbc(
          url = msqlURLWithCreds,
          table = query,
          new Properties()
        )
      )
```

`sparkSession.time` doesn't seem to do anything in-depth enough to measure the full load time of the sql.

The web UI is giving me timing for the entire Stage[image]

The green box is my `read and call cache on the DataFrame.

The only way I could come up with to split into a separate Stage was to perform an operation that required shuffling data; but then that introduced its own overheads.

Thanks,
Brent